# Counting in Erlang (how do I increment a variable?)

Tags: erlang

I've figured out the Erlang-style loops: tail-recursion with functions that take all the "variables that don't vary":

```
%% does something, 80 bytes at a time
loop(Line, File) -> loop(Line, File, 0).
loop(Line, File, Count) -> 
    do_something(Line, Count),
    case file:read(File, 80) of
        {ok, Line2} -> loop(Line2, File, Count + 1);
        eof -> file:close(File);
        {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
    end.
```

But, what is the best way to increment a counter in Erlang? In most programming languages, the way you count things is by incrementing a variable (ie. `count += 1;`). Erlang's variables don't vary, so we have to be creative. Fortunately, we have options...

We can pass a Counter variable with our functions, and increment it with each function call. We can use the process dictionary to store a count, and `get` and `put` to increment it. We can use ETS, the local data storage for processes. We can use a counter process (!!!):

```
loop(Count) ->                            
    receive                                   
        { incr } -> 
            loop(Count + 1);              
        { report, To } ->                     
            To ! { count, Count },            
            loop(Count)                           
    end.                                      

incr(Counter) ->
    Counter ! { incr }.

get_count(Counter) ->    
    Counter ! { report, self() },
    receive
        { count, Count } -> Count
    end.
```

I'm sure there are other ways too, depending on the scope. What's considered "best practice" for incrementing a variable in Erlang?

Comment: This question isn't too meaningful without a use case.  You can do `lists:foldl` to count things in a list (or `filter`+`length`).  If you're counting `gen_server` calls, you do that with your server's state easily.

Comment: I'm already missing PHP...
  static $i;
  $i++;

Answer (score 10):

Don't use the process dictionary.

The 'normal' loop that you are expecting (ie a `for` loop or a `do while`) is usually implemented in a recursive function in Erlang so if you are incrementing a 'normal' counter do it in the function calls like you show up top.

Don't use the process dictionary.

In case you missed, can I just point out that you should not use the process dictionary.

Comment: Also, don't use the process dictionary.

Comment: Yet strangely the process dictionary is used in almost every application in the Erlang/OTP distribution. Like `inets`.  Or `orber`.  Or `docbuilder`.  Or `ic`.  Or `megaco`.  Or `tv`.  Or `cosNotification`.  Or `eunit`.  Or `reltool`.  Or `compiler`.  Or `erts`.  Or `test_server`.  Or `appmon`.  Or `ssh`.  Or `debugger`.  Or `kernel`.  Or `gs`.  Or `os_mon`.  Or `pman`.  Or `stdlib`.  Or `percept`.  Or `xmerl`.  Or `asn1`.  Or `mnesia`.  Or `common_test`.  Or `parsetools`.  Or `dialyzer`.  Or...  It would be easier to believe the "no process dictionary" meme if the community stayed on message.

Comment: The general rule is that "if you wonder if you should use the process dictionary, you shouldn't use it" and "you'll know when you need it." To be fair, while there are valid process dictionary uses, most of them don't have to do with 'incrementing variables' but rather 'storing process metadata', as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, I agree there I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE.  I would never even consider using the process dictionary for incrementing variables.  I just think the mindless mantra "don't use the process dictionary" is silly given that, you know, the core distribution of Erlang and all its attendant libs makes extensive use of it.  Your wording is much better.  "If you wonder the answer is no" and "you'll know when you need it" makes far more sense.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what you are using the counter for. Anything global like the number of messages handled by q system should use ets:update_counter. If it is not global I usually just include it in the parameters like you showed.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this implementation of a for loop in Erlang:

```
for( Max, Max, F )  -> [ F(Max) ];
for( I, Max, F )    -> [ F(I) | for( I+1, Max, F ) ].
```

`F` is a function from which you can save results for values `I` to `Max`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of incrementing a counter is as in your first example.  By adding a variable to the call and incrementing it.  I think that you get confused by the lack of for loops and possibility to update values.

Note that:

```
repeat(Times) when Times >= 0 -> repeat(0, Times).

repeat(Times, Times) -> done;
repeat(N, Times) ->
  do_a_side_effect,
  repeat(N + 1, Times).
```

compiles to (more or less) the same thing as (in pseudo code):

```
repeat(Times) ->
  while (N < Times) {
    do_a_side_effect
    N++
  }
  return done
```

If you want to accumulate the result there are ways to do that as well.

Either use the lists package or accumulate the result yourself:

```
loop(File) ->
  {ok, Fd} = file:open(File),
  loop(Fd, 0, []).

loop(Fd, Count, Acc) ->
  case file:read(Fd, 80) of
    {ok, Line} ->
       Result = do_something(Line, Count),
       loop(Fd, Count + 1, [Result | Acc]);
    eof ->
      file:close(File),
      {Count, lists:reverse(Acc)};
    {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
  end.
```

Or something similar based on your example.

Edit: returned Count as part of the return value as well, since it seemed to be important.

Answer (score 1):

As of Erlang/OTP 21.2 (released in December 2018), you can use [the `counters` module](https://erlang.org/doc/man/counters.html).  The documentation sums it up well:

> This module provides a set of functions to do operations towards shared mutable counter variables. The implementation does not utilize any software level locking, which makes it very efficient for concurrent access. The counters are organized into arrays with the following semantics:
>
> - Counters are 64 bit signed integers.
> - Counters wrap around at overflow and underflow operations.
> - Counters are initialized to zero.
> - Write operations guarantee atomicity. No intermediate results can be seen from a single write operation.
> - Two types of counter arrays can be created with options `atomics` or `write_concurrency`. The `atomics` counters have good allround performance with nice consistent semantics while `write_concurrency` counters offers even better concurrent write performance at the expense of some potential read inconsistencies. See `new/2`.
> - Indexes into counter arrays are one-based. A counter array of size N contains N counters with index from 1 to N.

For example, let's create a counter, increment it by 7, and check the value:

```
> MyCounterRef = counters:new(1, [atomics]).
{atomics,#Ref<0.3460962489.1601830917.24209>}
> counters:add(MyCounterRef, 1, 7).
ok
> counters:get(MyCounterRef, 1).
7
```

So where do you store the counter reference, if more than one process needs access to it?  You can use [`persistent_term`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html) for that, also added in Erlang/OTP 21.2:

```
> persistent_term:put(my_counter_ref, MyCounterRef).
ok
> counters:add(persistent_term:get(my_counter_ref), 1, 9).
ok
> counters:get(persistent_term:get(my_counter_ref), 1).
16
```

Note that `persistent_term` should only be used for values that seldom or never change.  You would presumably create the counter when your application start, store the reference as a persistent term, and then access it while the application is running.