# Can Elixir / Erlang copy a process, including its memory?

Tags: process, erlang, elixir

I'm considering solving a problem using Elixir, mainly because of the ability to spawn large numbers of processes cheaply.

In my scenario, I'd want to create several "original" processes, which load specific, immutable data into memory, then **make copies of those processes as needed. The copies would all use the same base data**, but do different, read-only tasks with it; eg, imagine that one "original" has the text of "War and Peace" in memory, and each copy of that original does a different kind of analysis on the text.

My questions:

- Is it possible to copy an existing process, memory contents and all, in Elixir / the Erlang VM?
- If so, does each copy consume as much memory as the original, or can they share memory, as Unix processes do with the "copy on write" strategy? (And in this case, there would be no subsequent writes.)

Comment: Processes don't share, or rather only very limited specific types of data. Large binaries are shared.

Comment: I think I may have asked the wrong question. Looking back, I really wanted to ask "can I load or build some readonly data, spawn multiple processes, and have them all use it?" The answer is yes. Eg, the data could be stored in an Elixir module attribute or function body during compilation using a macro, and spawned processes could call the function or access the attribute at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in way to copy processes. The easiest way to do it is to start the "original" process and the "copies" and send all the relevant data in messages to the copies. Processes don't share data so there is no more efficient way of doing it. Putting the data in ETS tables only partially helps with sharing as the data in the ETS tables are copied to the process when they are used, however, you don't need to have all the data in the process heap.

Answer (score 5):

An Erlang process has no process-specific data apart from what's stored in variables (and [the process dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824520/113848)), so to make a copy of the memory of a process, just spawn a new process passing all relevant variables as arguments to the function.

In general, memory is not shared between processes; everything is copied.  The exceptions are ETS tables (though data is copied from ETS tables when processes read it), and binaries larger than 64 bytes.  If you store "War and Peace" in a binary, and send it to each worker process (or pass it along when you spawn those worker processes), then the processes would share the memory, only copying it if they wanted to modify the binary.  See the [chapter on binaries](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html) in the Erlang efficiency guide for more details.

Comment: Interesting. The actual data I want to share would be more like a dictionary, where keys are arrays of numbers and values are arrays of dictionaries. Would that be possible to share and use via a binary? (Sorry for the total newbie questions, but I'm trying to determine feasibility before I dive deep.)

Comment: I would start out with [ETS tables](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html). While the data would be copied when you read it out of the ETS table, if you're only looking at a part of it at the same time the worker process should be able to keep up with garbage collection.

Comment: I would go with ETS too or simply send the relevant data to the other processes on demand. However, if you benchmark and this is indeed a performance issue, you can encode your key-value as a large binary and have each process extract the information from there. IIRC, Kresten uses this technique in his HanoiDB application: https://github.com/krestenkrab/hanoidb

Comment: The trouble with using an ETS table is that each process does **not** have its own copy of the data to work with. Also using ETS mean that you will continually be copying data to/from the processes every time you access the data. Of course it depends on how you want these copies to work.

Comment: Sounds like a binary is more realistic here; the data can be several MB of JSON. The main point of using Elixir would be for speed, so copying this data every time wouldn't work. Would "extracting" the data from the binary be expensive? Eg, can I do 3MB of binary to maps of tuples of keyword lists in a few milliseconds? (At this point the answer is probably "try it", but if anybody knows that this will/won't work, it would save me a lot of time.)

Comment: @NathanLong You can extract data from a binary with term_to_binary/1. Yes you can share send the binary but it still means you **build** the data you extract so in the long run you don't win anything over sending the data in fact you probably lose as you extract, and rebuild, the same data multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of Erlang/Elixir processes as similar to Unix processes. They aren't at all, I really wish they had a different name, because they really aren't either threads or processes in the standard Unix sense. It took me some time to wrap my head around the differences.

You have to throw out all your preconceived ideas about processes, they are all wrong. Eprocesses have the following characteristics.

- They are cheap and fast. Use lot's, there are always more.
- They share no resources[1]. ( Even writing to stdout is a message to another Eprocess. )
- IPC ( or messages ) are very fast with relatively low overhead compared to standard Unix IPC.

What I would try in your case is to create a server that managed the data and have each analysis worker message the server for data chunks that it needs. It's perfectly acceptable to have an Eprocess be more or less a
manager of shared memory.

To me the most useful way to think of Eprocesses is as objects with their own thread of execution.

[1] Well, there is the ETS table, but it's best to think of them as not sharing resources until you absolutely have to.

Comment: They are processes, just not Unix processes. There are other systems than Unix. :-)

Comment: Actually I'd probably answer that question quite differently after another year of learning to use the BEAM.

Comment: Yes ETS tables aren't really shared. They are more like being globally accessible as data is copied between the tables and your process when you access them. Conceptually like them being process state, but they are implemented differently.