# How to generate a 32 bit big-endian number in the format 0x00000001 in erlang

Tags: erlang

I need to generate a variable which has the following properties - 
32 bit, big-endian integer, initialized with 0x00000001 (I'm going to increment that number one by one). Is there a syntax in erlang for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Erlang, normally you'd keep such numbers as plain integers inside the program:

```
X = 1.
```

or equivalently, if you want to use a hexadecimal literal:

```
X = 16#00000001.
```

And when it's time to convert the number to a binary representation in order to send it somewhere else, use bit syntax:

```
<<X:32/big>>
```

This returns a binary containing four bytes:

```
<<0,0,0,1>>
```

(That's a 32-bit big-endian integer.  In fact, big-endian is the default, so you could just write `<<X:32>>`. `<<X:64/little>>` would be a 64-bit little-endian integer.)

On the other hand, if you just want to print the number in `0x00000001` format, use `io:format` with this format specifier:

```
io:format("0x~8.16.0b~n", [X]).
```

The `8` tells it to use a field width of 8 characters, the `16` tells it to use radix 16 (i.e. hexadecimal), and the `0` is the padding character, used for filling the number up to the field width.

---

Note that incrementing a variable works differently in Erlang compared to other languages.  Once a variable has been assigned a value, you can't change it, so you'd end up making a recursive call, passing the new value as an argument to the function.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862593/113848) has an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation[1] the following snippet should generate a 32-bit signed integer in little endian.

```
1> I = 258.                              
258
2> B = <<I:4/little-signed-integer-unit:8>>.
<<2,1,0,0>>
```

And the following should produce big endian numbers:

```
1> I = 258.
258
2> B = <<I:4/big-signed-integer-unit:8>>.
<<0,0,1,2>>
```

[1] http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html